# Assign an ID to create a "View Details" on a table to link to a view

Tags: laravel, html-table

I have a table and want to add a "View Details" button for each row which links to a further details page, I have easily added the button but am looking for a little help to be able to make it open to the specific message it's related too.

My Current View:

```
 @extends ('layout')
@section('content')
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/filtering.js"></script>
    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.6/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>
                MESSAGES R US
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col ">
            <a href="/create" class="btn btn-primary">CREATE MESSAGE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col ">
            <a href="/details" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW DETAILS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> <!-- This works-->
        <table id="userTable" data-page-length='5' cellspacing="0"
               class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed"
               role="grid">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">CREATED</th>
                    <th scope="col">USERNAME</th>
                    <th scope="col">TO/FROM</th>
                    <th scope="col">UPDATED</th>
                    <th scope="col">MESSAGE ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">STATUS</th>
                    <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach ($messages as $message)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$message->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{$message->username}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                                    @if ($message->direction == 'from')
                                        <span class='badge badge-warning'>from</span>
                                    @else
                                        <span class='badge badge-success'>{{$message->direction}}</span>
                            @endif

                        </td>
                        <td>{{$message->updated_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{$message->message_id}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @if ($message->status == 'FAIL')
                                <span class='badge badge-danger'>FAIL</span>

                            @elseif ($message->status == 'received')
                                <span class='badge badge-info'>received</span>

                            @elseif ($message->status == 'delivered')
                                <span class='badge badge-primary'>delivered</span>

                            @elseif ($message->status == 'queued')
                                <span class='badge badge-warning'>queued</span>

                            @elseif ($message->status == 'read')
                                <span class='badge badge-success'>read</span>

                            @endif
                        </td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col "><a href="/details" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW</a></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div
@endsection
```

I have built this in Laravel, when VIEW is clicked it just displays the same table without being specific to the message's row, I don't know how to link it to further display the MESSAGE ID details. This is a leisure project so excuse the formatting and UI. I am new to laravel with previously using ASP.NET MVC. Any help is appreciated.

I understand the concept which I need to make it work. Use the message_ID as the key for the button, then utilize that tables data (MESSAGE_ID - MESSAGE_TEXT) I just need the help to connect the dots. :)

Comment: can you show us your details route? just run php artisan route:list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to declaration the "details route" in your route. Your route maybe will looks like this

```
Route::get('/message/{id}/details', 'YourController@details')->name('message.detail');
```

and then in your views the button will be call this route. so your Button views will be looks like

```
<a href="{{ route('message.detail', $message->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW</a>
```

And hen last in your controller. you must have method that you declare before in route (in my example the method name is "details").

```
public function details(Request $request, $id){
    // your detail code here
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you I will give it a try :) I am looking forward to it

Comment: When I use this it still returns all the records instead of one, I am going to attempt to use 

Retrieving A Record By Primary Key (Eloquent ORM)

$message = Message::find(1);

var_dump($message->message_id);

Comment: Also, your code definitely works but only when I remove "Request $request, $id" otherwise I get a variable error